# logback: CyclicBufferTracker.setMaxNumberOfBuffers() removed while official doc still refering it. what's alternative please?

Tags: logback, smtpappender

I'm use SMTPAppender in logback, and configured like this:

```
<appender name="ALARM-APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
  ...
  <cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTracker">
    <maxNumberOfBuffers>256</maxNumberOfBuffers>
  </cyclicBufferTracker>
  ...
</appender>
```

but I got this error while running:

> 10:00:48,171 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@82:24 - no applicable action for [maxNumberOfBuffers], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][cyclicBufferTracker][maxNumberOfBuffers]]

So I rechecked official manual:
  http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#bufferManagement
  It didn't tell where maxNumberOfBuffers should be config to.

Fortunately, I find a config example in official doc：
  http://logback.qos.ch/recipes/emailPerTransaction.html

```
<cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTracker">
    <maxNumberOfBuffers>512</maxNumberOfBuffers>
</cyclicBufferTracker>
```

Looks the same...

Then I checked latest java-doc for Class CyclicBufferTracker:
http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/spi/CyclicBufferTracker.html
No "setMaxNumberOfBuffers" method here or in it's parent Classes.

As last resorts, I checked the source code changing history in github:
https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/a052f15d09636698c96fcdb753da3270f5c01b11/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/spi/CyclicBufferTracker.java
In the original version,when it's still a interface, there are both "setMaxNumberOfBuffers" and "setBufferSize" method in it.

https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/commit/773193a09922ab2a1dd70e4978be8cdf4e050f6e
Apr 25, 2013, method "setMaxNumberOfBuffers" was removed.

Now there is a problem:  where should I config "setMaxNumberOfBuffers" to?
("setMaxNumberOfBuffers" has totally differet meaning from "setBufferSize")

It's can't even find and "maxNumberOfBuffers" String in logback's repository:
https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/search?q=maxNumberOfBuffers

I'm using lastest version of logback(1.1.2) by the way.
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the latest version is used. Got the same problem but with **bufferSize** property for logback version 1.0.9.
After some research found this 
[bug report](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-933). 
After updating to the latest version problem dissappeared.